# Notepad++ Replacement String with NUL Truncates After NUL

Tags: notepad++, regex, find-and-replace

Using Notepad++, I'm trying to replace a string (in a **binary** file) like this:

**A**`NUL`**p**`NUL`**p**`NUL`**l**`NUL`**e**`NUL`

With another string like this:

**O**`NUL`**r**`NUL`**a**`NUL`**n**`NUL`**g**`NUL`**e**`NUL`

So...

Using the following format of search regex, N++ finds all instances of the target-text just fine:

**A**`\x00`**p**`\x00`**p**`\x00`**l**`\x00`**e**`\x00`

But using the following **replacement string** like this:

**O**`\x00`**r**`\x00`**a**`\x00`**n**`\x00`**g**`\x00`**e**`\x00`

Replaces all instances found with:

**O**`NUL`

...and that's it. Everything in the replacement string after the first `NUL` is ignored.  I've googled, looked at the N++ wiki, and maybe I've missed it, but I don't see anything stating why this is happening. Seems like a "Null-termination" issue, but shouldn't search-and-replace be smart enough to handle this? Am I using it wrong?

Comment: It looks as though you are editing a Unicode file, but it's being read in as ASCII. Is it missing the initial `\xFF\xFE`? If it's opened with the correct encoding, then the search and replacement strings will just be `Apple` and `Orange` and everything should work normally.

Comment: No, it's a binary file, `*.accdb` to be specific.

Comment: Notepad++ is not designed to be binary file editor. It does however have a hex editor plugin. See [How do I install the Notepad++ Hex-Editor plugin?](//superuser.com/q/1324217)

Comment: The file you are editing is an Access database file, and it should not be edited with anything else (or compatible software); otherwise, you are liable to corrupt the database structure, especially since you are changing the length of a string. That said, I was unable to find or create Unicode data that NP++ didn't recognise as such. However, NotePadQQ (the Linux port of NP++) could be made to accept a Unicode text file as ASCII, and I was able to reproduce your findings, but I found it would work as you want if I select `Search with special characters` instead of with Regular Expressions.

Comment: @AFH I'm actually trying to replace an equal length string stored as a database property, the above was just an example.  The ultimate question was not about the implied X<>Y problem, as what I wanted to know was why Notepad++ ignores the replacement characters after the first "`\x00`."  That I am working with an accdb is immaterial to the question.

Comment: And does Extended work when you use it instead of RE?

Comment: When I use extended for the search, I can't seem to search for `NUL` followed by a number character because it interprets the number as part of the escape code. E.g., \07 should be `NUL`7, not "\7" escape.